# Animated scroll on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to find the code for this problem for ages but nothing works exactly the way I wanted.

So, is it possible to make smooth scroll down of 1000px automatically after the page has loaded (**$(document).ready**)? I take that some jquery is probably needed to achieve the animation effect, but I have  no clue how to do it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: jQuery is not *needed*, but it can surely help achieving this

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').animate({scrollTop:1000}, 500);
    });
```

Here's the fiddle! http://jsfiddle.net/2LEz3/1/

Comment: On the example works exactly how I wanted. However I know zero about javascript so could u tell where to put and what since I didn't get it work on my own website.


`<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>`

what goes and where

Comment: You put this Javascript inside a `<script></script>` tag, some people put it in header, others in the body. Since you're a beginner I suggest putting it (the script) in the `<head>` @richieahb

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').animate({'scrollTop': '1000px'}, 2000);
}
```